# Why does int's value change?

Tags: c

I have this C code:

```
int a = 5;
printf("a is of value %d before first if statement. \n", a);
if (a = 0) {
    printf("a=0 is true. \n");
}
else{
    printf("a=0 is not true. \n");
}
printf("a is of value %d after first if statement. \n", a);
if (a == 0){
    printf("a==0 is true. \n");
}
else{
    printf("a==0 is not true. \n");
}
return 0;
}
```

output:

```
a is of value 5 before first if statement.
a=0 is not true. 
a is of value 0 after first if statement. 
a==0 is true. 
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I do not understand why the int value is still recognized as 5 in the first statement, but changes to 0 before the 2nd if, or why it changes at all?

Comment: `a = 0` is an assignment, not a comparison

Comment: You're saying you don't understand why a=0 changes the value of a to 0?

Comment: You typoed the first if.  ANd it looks like it works because the result of an assignment is the valued assigned.  Which here is 0.  So it returns false.  You should write comparissons with constants as 0==a instead so this becomes a compile time error.

Comment: Doesn’t look like a typo to me, since he specifically repeated the assignment operation in the following two printf calls. Seems to me he’s trying to understand how exactly an assignment inside an if statement works in C. See my answer below.

Comment: Please mark the best answer as accepted. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 12):

When you do `if (a = 0)` you are setting the variable `a` to `0`. 
In C, this will also evaluate the expression to `0`.

So actually that if-statement works in two steps. It's as if you did:

```
a = 0; //assign 0 to a

if (a) {  ... } //evaluate a to check for the condition
```

In which case, since `a` is `0`, it evaluates to `false`. That's why you end up in the `else` of the first part, and in the second part `(a == 0)` evaluates to `true`!

Answer (score 5):

in the first if you need to use "==".

```
if(a == 0) {
```

Answer (score 2):

in `if (a = 0)` your assigning value `0` to `a`.

To do a comparison you should do in `if (a == 0)` (so with double `==`)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (a = 0)
```

In the above `if` statement, first `0` is assigned to the variable `a`. Then the condition is evaluated.

Because `a` now holds the value `0`, it is evaluated as `false` and the corresponding `else` block is executed.

**In C language, `true` is represented by any numeric value not equal to `0` and `false` is represented by `0`.**

> I do not understand why the int value is still recognized as 5 in the
>   first statement, but changes to 0 before the 2nd if, or why it changes
>   at all?

Because, after execution of the first if statement, value of `a` is `0`. So, when second `if` statement is evaluated, `a` has the value `0`, and thus the condition `if (a == 0)` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

0 is false, ie. not true.

That is why the first if-statement behaves like it does.

And a=0 assigns 0 to a, which is the reason for its value afterwards.